# Alternative to or proper use of lineChart and xyLineChart

Tags: java, jasper-reports

With the goal of exporting a line chart with X and Y axis labels, I've tried 2 approaches:

**1. cht.lineChart()**

Problem: `cht.lineChart().setValueAxisFormat(cht.axisFormat().setLabel("Label Name"))` results in an exported chart with no Y axis label.

**2. cht.xyLineChart()**

Problem: `cht.xyLineChart().setXValue(xColumn)` expects `xColumn` to be of type `TextColumnBuilder<Integer>`. My data set includes `String` values, so I need `xColumn` to be of type `TextColumnBuilder<String>`.

Does anyone know of an approach that would result in an exported line chart with both X and Y axes labeled, and with X axis values that may be of type `String`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a Customizer was overwriting `cht.lineChart().setValueAxisFormat(cht.axisFormat().setLabel("Label Name"))`

I was able to resolve this issue by removing that line, and adding the following line in the Customizer:

```
rangeAxis.setLabel("Label Name");
```

I used cht.lineChart() after all.